# Can anyone send me a link for best boilerplate in react redux?

Tags: react-redux

I want the perfect boilerplate for react redux. Can any one send me a github link?

Answer (score 0):

I have created react redux apollo graphql boilerplate. However recently I wanted to user react redux only so I created separate branch without apollo.

It is probably not the best thing out there but I used webpack2, react, redux and hot reloading. Also you can import almost anything in modules. I hope it will help you.

https://github.com/developer239/ReactReduxApolloGraphQLHotBoilerplate/tree/no-apollo

This question will probably be deleted.  **You should NOT ask for complete solutions. Stackoverflow should help you get your own code working.** I feel your pain though. Starting with react is really confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot men. This link you gave me would probably help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source library with a number of complete examples:
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples

It's an excellent resource while learning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a clutter-free solution to set up redux, redux-saga, redux-dev-tools and other essential stuffs, you may want to try : https://github.com/anish000kumar/redux-box

I guess docs are straightforward to get you up to speed!